# Android 4.1 AcousticEcho Canceler - is it a complete solution?

Tags: android

In Android 4.1, is the AcousticEchoCancel preprocessor an actual echo canceler or just a call to a separate non-Android code or hardware module?  I am building a speakerphone that needs an acoustic echo canceler and need to clarify whether running Android 4.1 gets me a complete version of this function.

Answer (score 0):

This effect is implemented in android framework and guaranteed to be available on any device running JB. 
It is not a wrapper for some native implementation.